# Why do all questions link to themselves?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, seo, search-engine

Every question links to itself in its H1 tag, and I was wondering why this is the case. This is also true for every post on Jeff Atwood's blog. Is this for SEO reasons?

I was warned against this from a peer of mine because it creates an infinite link loop. Any thoughts or explanation on the rationale behind this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because [recursion](https://www.google.com/#q=recursion) is awesome.

Comment: Did your peer give any actual _reasons_ for his aversion?

Comment: @servy I clicked that link and expected it to link to your comment.

Comment: @Mat'sMug So did I when I clicked it again yesterday.  I was disappointing in myself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't say what the idea was of putting it there, but I do find it useful because it lets people quickly grab a perm-link to the question itself. Since you might stumble upon the question by having received a link to [one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212732/why-do-all-stackoverflow-questions-link-to-themselves/212734#212734).

Also, the "infinite link loop" makes no sense, as it would only need two links that link to each other to create an infinite link loop. (Trust me, this exists on StackExchange as well as most other sites on the internet.) Bots crawling the internet are smart enough to remember which links where visited recently. And humans don't throw `StackOverflowError` or any kind of `Exception`, neither do they simply crash, when being faced against an infinite link loop.

A related feature is that clicking on the time [for a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212732/why-do-all-stack-overflow-questions-link-to-themselves/212734#comment684825_212732) gives you a perm-link to that specific comment.

Comment: This is most likely the correct answer.  Many blogs do this also, including [Wordpress](http://forum.graphene-theme.com/graphene-support/seo-complete-controle-over-h1-title-not-the-permalink-in-the-archive/page/2).

Comment: +1 for the funny explanation about people not throwing exceptions.

Comment: people cannot use the URL bar?

Comment: @tuskiomi The URL bar might lead to a comment on the post, or to an answer. The link in the H1 leads to the question itself.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that the reasons are twofold

1. To cause recursion and therefore a stack overflow of Stack Overflows
2. See item 1

No, but in all seriousness, I've used this several times before, especially when I'm editing or answering a question, and I don't want to copy and paste the URL into a new tab. I'm not sure what the original reasoning was, but that's just what I use it for. Perhaps it is SEO related?